# Restricting access to a particular column in Azure table storage

Tags: azure, azure-table-storage

We want to give access to our Azure table storage to one of the third-parties letting them update data in one column and restricting them modifying information in other columns. Is this possible by any means like SAS tokens?
They want to update using storage emulator.

**Note:** Other programmatic options are not possible for us as they are not willing to either use or expose an API so that we can handle this programmatically.

Answer (score 1):

> We want to give access to our Azure table storage to one of the
>   third-parties letting them update data in one column and restricting
>   them modifying information in other columns. Is this possible by any
>   means like SAS tokens?

As of now it is not possible. With Shared Access Signature (SAS) tokens, you can restrict the access to certain range of entities (by specifying PartitionKey/RowKey ranges) but all attributes of those entities will be available to the users fetching those entities.

Comment: Thanks. This answer helped me in the other way restricting row-level access :)